# Flowchart for complete Android application

Tags: android, lifecycle, flowchart

Has anyone come across a flowchart of the Lifecycle of the **whole Application**?
I've seen the Lifecycle flowchart for a **single Activity**

I know there is an object **Application** where it is possible to create and keep **global variables** accross Activities. This must be created *outside* the Activity Lifecycle.

I also read in some post that the **first Activity** is special and it gets destroyed last of all.

I also know that background tasks still execute even if the parent Activity is paused/stopped. Also would like to see their lifecylce.

It would be nice to have a complete graph of how Android OS creates and manages **ALL** the application components from birth to death.